# Android: Tab Layout

Tags: android

I'm trying to follow the example on the dev guide : 
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html
I don't understand step 2 : what should I should do to "add the corresponding  tags to the Android Manifest file." ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every Activity class you create and call in your application you need to add corresponding entries in your manifest file.

For example if our class was LoginActvitiy.java

We'd have to add:

```
<activity android:name=".LoginActivity"></activity>
```

Inside the `<application>` node in your manifest file.